# Value of input field is being removed by directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple Angular Problem - I think it's probably a case of can't see the wood for the trees here.

I have an input field with a directive attached. The purpose is eventually to compare new with old data and show a popup. However, as soon as I add the directive attribute to the input field, the value disappears:

Plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/BQvKGe6kjuD0ThPBYJ4d?p=preview

HTML:

```
First Name:
<input type='text' ng-model='currentEditItem.strFirstName' name='strFirstName' id='strFirstName' 
cm-popover="currentEditItem.personOldData.strFirstName"/>

<br><br>
ngModel: {{currentEditItem.strFirstName}} <br>
cmPopover: {{currentEditItem.personOldData.strFirstName}}
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.currentEditItem = {};
    $scope.currentEditItem.strFirstName = "Bob";
    $scope.currentEditItem.personOldData = {};
    $scope.currentEditItem.personOldData.strFirstName = "Roger";    
});


app.directive("cmPopover", function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            ngModel: "=",
            cmPopover: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("ngModel", scope.ngModel);
            console.log("cmPopover", scope.cmPopover);
        }
    }
});
```

If you go to the Plunk and remove the cm-popover attribute, the input field is filled with the value from the model. When the attribute is added the value disappears although the model is still in the scope with the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngModel` does not create a new isolated scope for itself so it can `$watch` without having to hardcode a `$parent` in it's internal code.
But then you add another directive on the same DOM node that creates an isolated scope for itself. Couple this with the fact that you can only have a single isolated scope on a DOM node and you basically force `ngModel` to use/work with the same scope `cmPopover` created.

So when writing `ng-model="currentEditItem.strFirstName"` you are actually addressing the `$scope` inside the `cmPopover` directive, no the one in the (parent) controller. You can check this is the case by using `ng-model="$parent.currentEditItem.strFirstName"` - and it will work.

There's quite a lengthy conversation [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1924) with a lot of possible workarounds and solutions that leads to an actual [fix in release 1.2.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-31).

So long story short: update to at least AngularJS 1.2.0 and this will work.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense now. An upgrade would mean testing an aweful lot of code so I guess the workaround will be the way to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your directive you declare an isolate scope. This input's scope is now this isolate scope since it's the directive element. It's looking for the currentEditItem object which doesn't exist in the isolate scope